# Xpath first occurrence of a tree

Tags: xpath, scrapy, lxml

I want to find the first occurrence of a tree. Example:

```
<div id='post>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<img src="a.jpg">
<img src="b.jpg">
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<img src="c.jpg">
<p>text5</p>
</div>
```

I want to find the first occurrence of "p/img/@src".

When i do xpath search:  `.//div/p/img[1]/@src`
it gives 2 hits, a.jpg and c.jpg

What is the xpath for only the first occurrence (a.jpg). 
I would say `.//div/(p/img)[1]/@src` but is of course not working.

Comment: The first occurance of `p/img/@src`? That would simply be `(p/img/@src)[1]`. But `p/img` means an `img` child element of a `p` parent element and your sample only `img` sibling elements of `p` elements.

Comment: but the parentheses "(" ")" won't work in lxml. I get this error:  exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //div[@id="post"]/div[@class="body"]/(p/img/@src)[1]

Comment: The parantheses should be:(//div[@id="post"]/div[@class="body"]/p/img/@src)[1]  Then it works. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be:

```
(//img[@src])[1]/@src
```

or

```
(//p//img[@src])[1]/@src
```

ensuring `img` itself within a `p` element.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin says `img` is not a child of `p`. Moreover in your example are missing single quote closing of `id` attribute inside `div` and tag closing of `img`.
Here your xml corrected:

```
<div id='post'>
   <p>text1</p>
   <p>text2</p>
   <img src="a.jpg"/>
   <img src="b.jpg"/>
   <p>text3</p>
   <p>text4</p>
   <img src="c.jpg"/>
   <p>text5</p>
</div>
```

Now to select the first image you can use simply `//img[1]/@src` or `//img[@src="a.jpg"]`

Comment: This was just an example to show my problem. In real time situations i don't know what the img src is.